# How to compute $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} w^{n^2} = \frac{1}{2}(1+i)\left(1+(-1)^N\right)$?

Tags: summation

For $w=\exp[\frac{2\pi i}{N}]$, (i.e $N$th root of $1$.)

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} w^{n^2} = \frac{1}{2}(1+i)\left(1+(-1)^N\right)
\end{align}
How one can show this equation explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in the question.If N is odd prime then $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}w^{n^2}$ is the Quadratic Gauss Sum $g(1;N)$ and it's value equals $\sqrt{N}$ when $N\equiv 1\mod 4$.But from the question the value of the sum equals 0 when $N$ is odd.

Comment: Yes in the paper, this states as Gauss' Sum, But there is no condition as $N$ is odd or even... I just wrote the statement in the paper...

Comment: When $N$ is a prime satisfying $N\equiv 1 \mod 4$ left hand side of your equation is $1$ and right hand side of your equation $\frac{1}{2}(1+i)(1+(-1)^N)=0$.